# Find Probability- generating function of $Z = Y -1$ where $Y \sim{\rm Geo}(p)$

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Let $Z = Y-1$ where $Y \sim {\rm Geo}(p)$.

Calculate $G(x) = E[x^Z]$, the probability generating function of $Z$.

What I have done so far is:

$$E[x^Z] = E[x^Yx^{-1}] = x^{-1}E[x^Y] = x^{-1}\sum^\infty_{k=0}p(1-p)^{k-1}x^{k} = \sum^\infty_{k=0}p(1-p)^{k-1}x^{k-1}$$

However I know this isn't right.

If I can get some hints on how to handle $Z = Y-1$ I'm sure I can solve it.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit

The key says:

For $x < \frac{1}{1-p}$ we have $G(x) = E[x^Z]=\sum^\infty_{k=0}p(1-p)^k\cdot x^k = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)x}$

From what I did I would get

$$\frac{p}{x(1-p)} + \sum^\infty_{k=1}p(1-p)^{k-1}x^{k-1} =\frac{p}{x(1-p)} + \frac{p}{1-(1-p)x}$$

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? Do you know the answer already?

Comment: What you have done is fine, except $k$ might run from $1$ to $\infty$ depending on the form of the pmf.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late answer. I made an edit to my post, is the answer in the key wrong then?